# Counting individual values separated by a comma in cells with a in cell list data validation

Tags: excel, vba

In column E of my sheet, I have a in cell drop down list data validation with the options (CAIOS, ERCOT, MISO, PJM, SPP). And I wrote a VBA to allow multi selection in each cell. I have cells [PJM], [PJM], [PJM], [PJM], [PJM, SPP]. I am trying to count if cell CONTAINS PJM. I am using wildcards but the result is always 4 and not 5.

Comment: If you have `[PJM], [PJM], [PJM], [PJM], [PJM, SPP]` in `A1` then `=(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"PJM","")))/3` will return 5; if you have `[PJM]` in `A1:A4` and `[PJM, SPP]` in `A5` then `=COUNTIF(A1:A5,"*PJM*")` will return 5

Comment: Please share your code in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your case:

```vb
Function CountPJMOccurrences(cellValue As String) As Long
    Dim selections() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim countPJM As Long
    
    ' Split cell contents based on comma
    selections = Split(cellValue, ",")
    
    ' Loop through the array and count occurrences of "PJM"
    For i = LBound(selections) To UBound(selections)
        If Trim(selections(i)) = "PJM" Then
            countPJM = countPJM + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    CountPJMOccurrences = countPJM
End Function
```

You can use this function in your worksheet; for example, if your cell with the dropdown list is in cell E1, you can enter the following formula in F1:

```
=CountPJMOccurrences(E1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used GPT to build upon Mark's answer and ended up using this and it worked.

```
Function CountAESOOccurrencesInColumn() As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim countAESO As Long
    
    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RFP_Details")
    
    ' Initialize count
    countAESO = 0
    
    ' Loop through all cells in column E
    For Each cell In ws.Range("E:E")
        If InStr(1, cell.Value, "Canada-AESO", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            countAESO = countAESO + 1
        End If
    Next cell
    
    ' Return the count
    CountAESOOccurrencesInColumn = countAESO
End Function
```